# Why can't I not use the now variable in bug fix for django poll tutorial part 5

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to Python and Django.  I am working on the poll tutorial and decided to post a question here that is more with Python than Django...
In `Writing Your First Django App, part 5`, -> `Writing our first test`, they presented a bug and then created a test to expose the bug, running the test will cause the test to fail.

The fix is as follows -> amend the method in `models.py` indicated below -> the test will return `true`.

```
def was_published_recently(self):
     now = timezone.now()
     return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <  now
```

My question is this, when I type below without substituting variable `now`, the test will `fail`.  Why is that?  It's not a simple substitution?

```
def was_published_recently(self):
     return timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < timezone.now()
```

Comment: Did you actually write that code with invalid [**indentation**](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html) (`def` and `return` starting on the same column)? That would cause a syntax error, and the test to fail.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, after your substition, timezone.now() is called twice, and those times not neccesserily the same(maybe milliseconds difference). I don't know if this is the reason tho.

Comment: Besides the indentation (which seemed just to be a copy&paste issue), the real mistake is in calling now() twice, exactly like @utdemir described.

Comment: @LukasGraf:  the indentation is  proper, I edited to reflect that.  I am new to stackexchange, my apologies.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed, no worries. Indentation was the first thing that jumped out at me, should have looked at the code :)

Comment: @utdemir and everyone else:  While true, that doesn't seem to be the correct answer; the [example test referenced in the OP](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial05/) puts `pub_date` 30 days in the future.

Comment: @chanquest Unless you wrote the test differently?

Comment: @Izkata, you are right.  It works now.  I must of had a mistype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to understand the difference is with some examples:

```
In [4]: timezone.now() == timezone.now()
Out[4]: False

In [5]: a = timezone.now()
In [6]: a == a
Out[6]: True


In [11]: print timezone.now() - timezone.now()
-1 day, 23:59:59.999984

In [12]: print a - a
0:00:00
```

You should notice each time you call `timezone.now()`, you get a different time.

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first function gets the current time and then saves that value in the variable `now`.  This value is then used twice (unchanged) in the next line.

The second function however calls `timezone.now` twice.  This means that you will get two **different** times;  one for each call.  Granted they will only be off by a few milliseconds at the most, but it is still a difference.

Remember that each time you call `timezone.now`, it will return the **current** time.  Consequentially, no two calls will return the same value.

Comment: @chanquest - Happy to help!  Don't forget to accept an answer though (click the tick) so people know this question is answered.